# How to build executables for specific platforms in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net-core, cross-platform

My question is what it says in the title. I want to build my C# application into executables for Windows, Linux and MacOS, such that I can put them in a release on my github repo. How do I do that? Maybe a makefile or something like that to create all at once would be handy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .NET Core 3.x or later, you can use `dotnet publish` with various options to [produce stand-alone executables](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/06/20/publishing-a-single-exe-file-in-net-core-3-0/):

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

You will need to re-run this command for each platform (Windows, macOS, Linux) that you want to target:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true
dotnet publish -c Release -r osx-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

`-p:PublishSingleFile=true` produces a single executable that you can copy around and run. You can attach it as an artifact with the release on GitHub.

(Aside: This executable will automatically extract itself into a few dozen files and then run that version. That means that you wont be able to run it, for example, on a system without a disk that you can write to.)

And yes, you can definitely wrap this up in a `Makefile` or something. Here's an example from a cli tool that I work on:

```
publish:
    dotnet publish \
    -c $(CONFIGURATION) \
    -r $(RUNTIME) \
    -p:PublishSingleFile=true
```